# Manjaro window borders green after update

Tags: xfce, manjaro

I just upgraded my Manjaro installation to version 0.8.12. I didn't notice any difference right away, but after i rebooted the computer the top window border on every window turned green.

[image]

I really don't like that color, and I would like to turn it back to black or gray. I have tried to change the XFCE theme, but the border stays the same.

How can I change the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Somehow the update made compiz override the settings. Setting the theme in compiz fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of xfwm4 themes on AUR, you can try them.
If nothing works, remove the local configuration (~/.themes, ~/.config/xfce4...) and copy /usr/share/themes, /usr/share/xfce4 instead.

You should also read [this article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfwm)